# get and show push data from serviceworker in chrome

Tags: javascript, service-worker, pushwoosh

I use pushwoosh for receive push notification in my web app.
every things working well and received push message in serviceworker listener but I want give push messge data from serviceworker and process it in  another js class

main.js  like this:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  console.log('Service Worker is supported');
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function() {
    return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
  }).then(function(reg) {
    console.log('Service Worker is ready :^)', reg);
      // TODO
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Service Worker error :^(', error);
  });
}

// get push message data in main.js and process it
```

service worker like this :

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Push message', event);

  var title = 'Push message';

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      'body': 'The Message',
      'icon': 'images/icon.png'
    }));
});
```

Comment: Using a *service* worker for this seems odd. Why that rather than a standard worker?

Comment: pushwoosh sdk use serviceworker

Comment: I can't find evidence of that on their website, but whatever. Presumably if they do, they have a reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, this seems a slightly odd use-case for a service worker rather than a standard worker, but:

You can have your service worker send a message to all connected clients when it gets a message pushed to it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704739/157247) shows a complete example of a service worker talking to clients, but fundamentally:

1. The pages it manages listen for messages:

   ```
   navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
       // use `event.data`
   });
   ```
2. The service worker sends to them like this:

   ```
   self.clients.matchAll().then(all => all.forEach(client => {
       client.postMessage(/*...message here...*/);
   }));
   ```

Or with ES5 and earlier syntax (but I don't think any browser supporting service workers doesn't also support arrow functions):

Page listening:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    // use `event.data`
});
```

Worker sending:

```
self.clients.matchAll().then(function(all) {
    all.forEach(function(client) {
        client.postMessage(/*...message here...*/);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for response .i put first code in html page and secend code under self.addEventListener('push', function(event)  but client (html page)  not give any message from serviceworker

Comment: @Roox: The above definitely works, but you have to remember the lifecycle of service workers, in particular the fact that the page that installs the worker doesn't then become a client of the worker until/unless it's refreshed. I'm still not at all sure a service worker is correct for this, but that's up to you.

Comment: clients.matchAll() return a empty array

Comment: @Roox: So clearly no clients are attached to the worker when it receives the push. Again, using a service worker for this just doesn't make sense. I'm not even seeing the need for a web worker at all.

Comment: for me, this code is not working. event.data is always empty.