# Get document inside setBackgroundMessageHandler function of fcm

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Below is my fcm `setBackgroundMessageHandler` function:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };
var event = new CustomEvent("name-of-event", payload);

// Dispatch/Trigger/Fire the event
document.dispatchEvent(event);
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});
```

I am unable to access `document` in above method. I have tried to save document in global variable and access it inside above method but it does not work.

```
var document = document;
.
.
.
document.dispatchEvent(event); // gives error: dispatchEvent of undefined
```

Comment: As far as I know your background handler runs in a service worker, which doesn't have access to the DOM. You use `postMessage()` to send messages between the service worker and the main page though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704641/access-dom-by-web-worker

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is there any way to prevent notification in `setBackgroundMessageHandler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `document` is not accessible in service worker. So there is no way to use its `dispatchEvent` function to emit event to Main page.

To Send message from service worker to `Main page` we can use `BroadcastChannel`. In Main page create a listener like this:

```
var listener = new BroadcastChannel('listener');
listener.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Got message from service worker',e);
};
```

In `service worker js` file use `BroadcastChannel` 's `postMessage` function to send message to main page:

```
var listener = new BroadcastChannel('listener');
listener.postMessage('It works !!');
```